# Very new to PHP and very interested to learn. If statements and Functions

Tags: php, function, if-statement, verify, statements

PLS. I am very NEW to PHP so pls. understand.
OK so here it goes. . What I want to know first is that "Can a function and an if statement be in one code?" second for the code below, just take a look at where the NOTE is, what should i type in the if statement to make it say " ARE THE SAME" if the values of the parameters $first and $second are the same and say " ARE NOT THE SAME" if not.

```
    <?php
    function verify($first,$second)
    {
    echo $first . " and " . $second ;
    }
    echo
    verify ("1","2");

    if ($first === $second) /* **NOTE: I know this is wrong cause its not working** */
    echo " ARE THE SAME";
    else
    echo " ARE NOT THE SAME";
    ?>
```

I think thats about it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: It's nice to know that you are interested in PHP :-) However, please *start with a book/tutorial* and follow along with it!

Comment: Google is your friend, as is http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Comment: manual != tutorial (although having a *reference* handy is always good)

Comment: any tips for a good reference, tutorial book? I'm actually using "Learning PHP, MySQL, Javascript - Robin Nixon" TNX! ps The PHP MANUAL is a PAIN TO READ SORRY :|

Comment: @user1429811 Learn to love the manual. It is the source of truth

Comment: wow. your comment actually inspired me to read the manual LOL! ok ill start using the manual from now on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is one of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Outside `verify()`, `$first` and `$second` are not defined. You could simply include the rest of your code inside the function body which would do what you want, eg

```
function verify($first,$second) {
    echo $first . " and " . $second ;

    if ($first === $second) {
        echo " ARE THE SAME";
    } else {
        echo " ARE NOT THE SAME";
    }
}

verify("1", "2");
```

... however functions that write to the output buffer are rarely a good idea. Instead, encapsulate the logic inside your function and leave the display to procedural code, eg

```
function verify($a, $b) {
    return $a === $b;
}

$first = '1';
$second = '2';
echo $first, ' and ', $second;
if (verify($first, $second)) {
    echo ' are the same';
} else {
    echo ' are not the same';
}
```

Comment: Ok now i get it! tnx for the help. The second sample is more complicated but if its more advisable then ill go with that. THANKS AGAIN, REALLY HELPED!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) you'll see that `===` will only be true, if both entered vars are of the same type. Usually, if a function returns `true` you can still use `if($returncode == 1)` and it would be true, whereas `if($returncode === 1)` would be false. You'd have to use `if($returncode === true` to trigger the if statement.

Also, you'll have to put the second if statement into the function, since the variables which you declare with functions are local, meaning it will only be accessible within the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function verify($first,$second)
    {
    if($first===$second){
     return "Same";
    } else {
     return "Different";
    }
    }
    echo verify ("1","2");
    ?>
```